# Ionic 2 - update Input value on change of original value

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have this app where I want to dynamically update a variable marked as `Input`.

In my ts I have something like this:

```
@Component({
   selector: 'page2',
   templateUrl: 'page2.html',
   inputs: ['currentTitle']
})
export class Page2 {
   currentTitle: string;

   constructor() {
     console.log(currentTitle);
   }
}
```

and in my HTML of the parent page:

```
 <page1 [example]="post.title"></page1>
```

Now I know that `currentUsername` will not be loaded in the constructor, but just for demo purpose.

What I want is that if the `post.title` changes, the `currentTitle` gets changed as well without having to, for example, reload.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leave your HTML as is, in your `ts` you should change your variable to look like the following:

```
@Input set currentTitle(value: string) {
    if(value != undefined){
      this._currentTitle = value;
    }
}

_currentTitle: string
```

Now use your `_currentTitle` instead of `currentTitle` (or do change the HTML to `_currentTitle` and swap variablenames.)